# Norton door closer - older model - how to adjust?

Tags: doors, hinges, closer

I've tried searching and cant seem to find what model this is or how to adjust it. This door slams shut and I want to adjust it to slow down.

[image]

https://imgur.com/a/3JgZ4tJ

Comment: See that round thing with a slot, adjacent to the circle with the hex?  Try rotating that (with a flarhead screwdriver) in either direction and see if the closing speed changes.